# make map where user enters text

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm making a custom map for myself where I can play certain battle simulations out to see how units fare against each other (and practice micro).

I would love to prompt the player for text input like this "which units do you want created this time?", and then have a string parser parse input like "2 zeal, 4 marine" and automatically create an army with whatever I textually ask for. I can think of no faster way.

So my question is: is there any trigger which can receive textual input from user?

If you can think of a better way to do what I want, then please place that as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You may want to look around the map-making community at the open RPG maps. I know they make heavy use of text based commands to script units, upgrades, etc. Unfortunately the only mapping resource I know about is http://www.sc2mapster.com/ I'm sure that someone there will have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Have you tried one of the unit test maps? Typically there will be two halves of the map with every building from every race on each side. All units and upgrades build very quickly (less than one second), so it's easy to create two opposing armies and have them go at each other.

Comment: There are some unit testing maps (can't remember right now sorry) that give you a picture of the units on the left side of the screen and you click on the portrait to create one or shift-click to create 5 of the unit. Something like http://www.sc2mapster.com/maps/unit-tester/

Comment: as mentioned in the [faq](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), mod development is considered off topic. Try gamedev.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a trigger on the event [(Player) types a chat message containing (list of strings)](http://www.sc2mapster.com/wiki/galaxy/triggers/events/chat-message/)

This is how maps like *Nexus Word Wars* or *YABOT* accept textual input.  There is no other way to accept textual input besides through the chat window.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typing game called Nexus Word Wars where you have to type the word above approaching units to destory them.

---

If the map is unlocked, you can directly open it up in the editor and see what triggers and code they use.

If it's locked, then hopefully it has the creator's contact info and you can ask the map author directly.

Comment: Closest answer so far

Comment: @Bora Yeah I've only made BW maps, so I don't know the exact answer